# How to sort an array by item type where strings should appear 1st then floats and integers while keeping same type precedence and no extra arrays used

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, sorting, comparison

Input:

```
[7,"a","b",5, 0.1, "c", 0.5, 9, 1, "e", "m", 0.3, 8.5, 74, 89,"f","r",0.5 ,"x", "y", 4, 7]
```

Output:

```
["a", "b", "c", "e", "m", "f", "r", "x", "y", 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 8.5, 0.5, 7, 5, 9, 1, 74, 89, 4, 7]
```

```
function sorter(arr) {
    var arr1, arr2, arr3;
    arr1 = [];
    arr2 = [];
    arr3 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] === "string") {
            arr1.push(arr[i]);
        } else if (typeof arr[i] === 'number' && !isNaN(arr[i])) {
            if (Number.isInteger(arr[i])) {
                arr3.push(arr[i]);
            } else {
                arr2.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3];
}
```

Comment: Do you want to edit the sort comparator function? What happens when you run your current code

Comment: Using mixed type arrays like this is probably an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to begin with. Are you _sure_ you want the data in this form and there isn't a better representation? As long as you keep the data in this form, your algorithms to work with it are going to be awkward, fully of branches to check types everywhere.

Comment: I have added the output for my current code. Just that I want to optimize my sorter function without taking any extra arrays.

Comment: Sorrting "integers" first makes no sense in JS because JS does not have integers. "12.0" and "12" are exactly the same number, so what would happen if your input was `[11, 12.0, 12]`?

Comment: @Ankita ... There is a lean approach based on a single sort comparator callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach based on a single [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) comparator callback ...

```js
function orderByItemTypeOnly(a, b) {
  const precedences = {
    'string': 1,
    'float': 2,
    'int': 3,
  };
  const getType = val =>
    ((typeof val === 'number') && Number.isFinite(val))
      ? Number.isInteger(val) && 'int' || 'float'
      : (typeof val);

  const aType = getType(a);
  const bType = getType(b);

  return (
    (precedences[aType] || 4) - (precedences[bType] || 4)
  );
}

console.log([

  7, "a", "b", 5, 0.1, "c", 0.5, 9, 1, "e", "m",
  0.3, 8.5, 74, 89, "f", "r", 0.5, "x", "y", 4, 7

].sort(orderByItemTypeOnly));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

There is also the possibility of solving this task not by `sort` but based on a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) approach ...

```js
function collectAndShiftItemByType(list, item, idx, arr) {
  if (list.length === 0) {
    list.push([], [], [], []);
  }
  const typeListIndex = ((typeof item === 'number') && Number.isFinite(item))
    ? (Number.isInteger(item) && 2 || 1)
    : (typeof item === 'string') ? 0 : 3;

  // push into sub lists ... [0]string, [1]float, [2]integer, [3]unknown.
  list[typeListIndex].push(item);

  if (idx >= arr.length - 1) {
    list = list[0]
      .concat(list[1])
      .concat(list[2])
      .concat(list[3]);
  }
  return list;
}

console.log([

  7, "a", "b", 5, 0.1, "c", 0.5, 9, 1, "e", "m",
  0.3, 8.5, 74, 89, "f", "r", 0.5, "x", "y", 4, 7

].reduce(collectAndShiftItemByType, []));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sort()` method with a comparison function that compares types rather than values.

```js
function sorter(arr) {
  function type_index(val) {
    const types = ["string", "float", "integer"];
    let type;
    if (typeof val == "string") {
      type = "string";
    } else if (typeof val == "number" && Number.isInteger(val)) {
      type = "integer";
    } else if (typeof val == "number" && !isNaN(val)) {
      type = "float";
    }
    return types.indexOf(type);
  }

  return arr.sort((a, b) => type_index(a) - type_index(b));
}

console.log(sorter([7,"a","b",5, 0.1, "c", 0.5, 9, 1, "e", "m", 0.3, 8.5, 74, 89,"f","r",0.5 ,"x", "y", 4, 7]));
```